# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) python if elif else statement for matplotlib

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib

I have created code that calculates the maximum Lyapunov exponents against two parameters a and b. This plots ok, however there is a chunk of the graph that is white where the graph is collapsing due to my x and y values equalling zero. Therefore, I need to set these equal to say 100 or similar to prevent this from happening and producing a fully coloured meshgrid plot.

I have already tried if statements but I either get a syntax error or another error a.any() a.all() when I substitute one of these into my if statement it returns another error. I have tried if elif and else statements and returning values. There is an error in them statements returning

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

```
d= 0.1
eps = 0.000001
#xnew equation
def f(a,b,xold,yold):
    m= a*xold*(1-b*yold)*(1-xold*(1-b*yold))
    if np.any(m>eps):
        return m
    else:
        return 50

#ynew equation
def g(b,d,xold,yold):
    n= (1-d)*yold*(1+b*xold)
    if np.any(n>eps):
        return n
    else:
        return 100
#Jacobian matrix equations. A,B,C,D    
def A(a,b,xold,yold):
    return a*(1-2*xold- b*yold+ 4*b*xold*yold- 2*(b**2)*xold*(yold**2))

def B(b,a,xold,yold):
    return a*b*xold*(2*xold- 1- 2*b*xold*yold)

def C(b,d,yold):
    return (1-d)*b*yold

def D(b,d,xold):
    return (1-d)*(1+b*xold)

#ml equation using ABCD     
def e(a,b,xold,yold,ydash):
    return (((A(a,b,xold,yold)+(B(b,a,xold,yold)*ydash))**2 +(C(a,b,yold)+(D(b,d,xold)*ydash))**2) / (1 + ydash**2))


#ydash equation using ABCD
def yz(a,b,xold,yold,ydash):
    return (C(b,d,yold)+(D(b,d,xold)*ydash))/(A(a,b,xold,yold)+(B(b,a,xold,yold)*ydash))
```

The equations are in another cell defined as functions.

```
#diff values of a and b looping 
a=np.linspace(0,6,80)
b=np.linspace(0,5,80)

def lyapunov(a,b):
    #initial conditions
    a,b = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    d = 0.1
    xold = 0.5
    yold = 0.01
    ee = 0.000001
   #xnew and ynew values
   for k in range(1000):
       xnew=f(a,b,xold,yold)
       ynew=g(b,d,xold,yold)
       xold = xnew
       yold = ynew

    if np.any(xnew<ee) and np.any(ynew<ee):
        ml = 100
        return ml

    elif np.any(xnew>ee) and np.any(ynew<ee):
        ml = 50
        return ml

    else:
        ml=0   
        for l in range(100):
            ydash=1
            ml = ml + np.log(abs(e(a,b,xold,yold,ydash)))

            ydash = yz(a,b,xold,yold,ydash) 
            xold=f(a,b,xold,yold)
            yold=g(b,d,xold,yold)

        ml = (ml/(2*100))
        return  ml

z = lyapunov(a,b)
ax.set_title('Lyapunov Exponent')
c = ax.pcolormesh(z)
fig.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

I expect a completed mesh grid with no white of colour showing the system collapsing therefore very small 0 and therefore halfing the run time. At present only half the plot is coloured. ERROR is returning 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. I presume the "if, elif, else" block should be inside the `lyapunov` function? At the moment you have it outside that function. Also, can you turn this into a [MCVE]? We don't have access to your `f` and `g` functions, so can't run your code.

Comment: First of all, I can detect an error of indentation in your code: the if statement is not in function `lyapunov`.

Comment: you need also to give us functions `yz` and `e` as well

Comment: 1. You don't plot anything so your colormesh does nothing. 2. `lyapunov` function returns only one number for two arrays, but `pcolormesh` needs the matrix. 3. `pcolormesh` needs at least three arguments: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh 4. The first three points make your question very hard to understand. It is hard to predict what exactly you want to draw on your graph.